# JAVA specific loop over Array 2D

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

I have this array :

```
 int[][] multi = new int[][]{
              { 3, 4, 2},
              { 2, 2, 5 },
              { 1, 2 }
            };
```

I would like to print the produce of each cells. It's pretty hard to explain so lets see some example :
        For my table i need to print :

```
        6 //(3*2*1)
        12 //(3*2*2)
        6 //(3*2*1)
        12 //(3*2*2)
        15 //(3*5*1)
        30 //(3*5*2)
        8 //(4*2*1)
        16 //(4*2*2)
        8 //(4*2*1)
        16 //(4*2*2)
        20 //(4*5*1)
        40 //(4*5*2)
```

...

Size of table can change, i need a generic things.

Here is my start but it's not doing what i need. This is looping line by line...

```
   for (int i = 0; i<multi[0].length; i++) {
           for (int k = 0; k < multi.length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < multi[k].length; l++ ) {
                    System.err.println(multi[k][l]);
                }    
           }   
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain where these values come from? E.g., I don't understand how `multi` produces `2,5,2`.

Comment: Do you need to print in that exact order?

Comment: They are all combinations created by using one number per cell.
It's printed backwards in this example.

Comment: i edited what i need to print, sorry

Comment: Where are you getting these expressions? It's not clear what pattern you're using to generate the product expressions. It's not down the column or across the row. Please clarify what calculations you want to make from a given table. Also - the code block you've written is just for printing, not doing any multiplication, so I don't see how it relates to your posed question?

Comment: @Mureinik I have simplify my code here, my pb is to transform something like this (5x^2+3x+2)(x^3-5)(4x^3-2x+4) into Ax^3 + Bx^2 - C, maybe with that you can understand why i need this kind of produces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you have to do that `recursively` if your *dimensions of array is not fixed*..
I came up the code for dynamic dimension of `2D array`

```
public class HelloWorld{
    static int[][] multi = new int[][]{
              { 3, 4, 2},
              { 2, 2, 5 },
              { 1, 2 }
    };
    static public void pattern(int row,int multip) {
        if(row >= multi.length) {
            System.out.println(multip);
            return ;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<multi[row].length;i++) {
            multip*=multi[row][i];
            row+=1;
            pattern(row,multip);
            row-=1;
            multip/=multi[row][i];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        pattern(0,1);
    }
}
```

If your *dimensions are fixed* then you can also do that using above logic but for that if you want to do **iterative** then you have to **repeatedly** create loops inside  loop.

Comment: It can be done with an iterative algorithm without create loops inside loop

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to explain if you use mathematics terms and what you need is simply a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the sets (i.e. each row) in your bidimensional array.
It could be a bit longer to explain here the theory about Cartesian product (X is the operator) but in practice you have to calculate the result of:

```
((multi[0] X multi[1]) X ...) X multi[n]
```

And you ends with a bidimensional array with a number of rows which is the product of all the cardinality of each set and each row has a number of elements which is the number of the sets (because each tupla has an element from each set).

Another thing is that the tuple are ordered i.e. the element of a set will be in the same position in all the tuples e.g. each tupla in position 0 will have an element of multi[0].

Knowing these properties is possible to create the product with a construction algorithm which puts the elements of the first set in the first column of the resulting set repeating them the necessary amount of time and then go on with the next set/next column.

At the end when you have your Cartesian product you can do anything you want e.g. calculate the product of the elements of each row.

```
public class CartesianProductProduct {

    public int[][] product(int[][] sets) {
        int cardinality = 1;
        for (int is = 0; is < sets.length; is++) cardinality *= sets[is].length;
        int[][] cartesianProduct = new int[cardinality][sets.length];
        int curCardinality = 1;
        for (int is = 0; is < sets.length; is++) {
            curCardinality *= sets[is].length;
            int repetition = cardinality / curCardinality;
            int ie = 0;
            for (int ic = 0; ic < cardinality; ic++) {
                cartesianProduct[ic][is] = sets[is][ie];
                if (repetition == 1) {
                    ie++;
                } else if ((ic + 1) % repetition == 0) {
                    ie++;
                }
                ie = ie == sets[is].length ? 0 : ie;
            }
        }
        return cartesianProduct;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] multi = new int[][]{
                {3, 4, 2},
                {2, 2, 5},
                {1, 2}
        };

        int[][] cartesianProduct = new CartesianProductProduct().product(multi);

        for (int i = 0; i < cartesianProduct.length; i++) {
            int prod = 1;
            String s = "";
            String sep = "";
            for (int k = 0; k < cartesianProduct[i].length; k++) {
                prod *= cartesianProduct[i][k];
                s = s + sep + cartesianProduct[i][k];
                sep = "*";
            }
            System.out.printf("%s //(%s)\n", prod, s);
        }
    }

}
```